# Jquery on first click one alert, on second click 2 alerts and so on. But need only 1 alert on each click

Tags: jquery

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/7vH2q/7/

On click want to get number of row in table. Latter will use the number to execute another code.

To test what I get, used `alert`

And see strange behavior. If i click first time on button, see 1 alert, click again, see 2 alerts and so on. I expect on each click to see alert only one time.

Here is code

```
<td id="1"><div style="width:30px; border:0px solid #F1F1F1;">

<input name="paid_used" type="button" value="" 
onClick="javascript:ajax_post_one_row(); ">

</div></td>
```

This is jquery code

```
function ajax_post_one_row(){

$("table tr").click(function(){
alert (this.rowIndex+1);
});

}
```

What need to do to see only 1 alert on each click? Actually i use alert only for testing (on working code i will comment the alert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an event handler inside an event handler, so everytime you click, you add another event handler, and the next time you click there are two, then three etc.

Remove the inline handler and stick with just the jQuery handler

```
<td id="1">
    <div style="width:30px; border:0px solid #F1F1F1;">
        <input name="paid_used" type="button" value="" />
    </div>
</td>
```

js

```
$("table tr").on('click', function(){
        alert (this.rowIndex+1);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rpc9/)

Answer (score 1):

`.one()` attaches a handler which is executed at most once per element per event type.

Write:

```
$("table tr").one("click",function(){
    alert (this.rowIndex+1);
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7vH2q/14/)

[More info here.](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation of the problem:**

On each click of the button (i.e. within the attached handler "ajax_post_one_row") you attach a new handler to the click on "table tr".

**Solution:**

Do it simpler way, attach only one handler to all buttons within the table:

```
$(document).on("click", "table input[type=button]", function() {
  alert($(this).closest("tr").attr("id"));
});
```

Another advice: use row IDs, not row numbers.

I slightly modified your example, now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/akhikhl/TVxA4/3/